# Utility to create an ERD from an already existing MySQL DB?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have my database built already, but I really want to print out an erd to reference while I'm building my models.  Is there a utility that can generate an erd from a SQL dump or by connecting to the database directly?

Thanks in advance,

~Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) should be able to do this.

Comment: Perfect.  I'm always using phpmyadmin and wasn't aware of this tool.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The *Data Modelling* component of MySQL Workbench 5.2 OSS can do what you are describing, depending on the ERD notation you are seeking.

From the Home tab, select **Create EER Model from Existing Database**, then simply follow the wizard that displays. It will you run you through connecting to an RDBMS, choosing the objects to model, and then create the model for you.

If you're looking for traditional Chen or Crow's Foot notation, make sure you select *Classic* in the Model > Object Notation menu, and Crow's Foot in the Model > Relationship Notation menu.

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)